# Annotation Processor - Multiple modules

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I have 3 modules. Two of them have generated classes, and on the third I would like to generate a mapper based on the generated classes from the other two modules.

I've added the other 2 modules as dependencies to the 3 modules, but the annotation processor never gets called.

The generated classes have the correct annotation, and if I create a class with the annotation on the third module, the annotation processor gets called.

My feeling is that the 3 module is unable to get the classes from the other modules because they are already compiled.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":module-1"))
    implementation(project(":module-2"))

    annotationProcessor(project(":processor"))
}
```

Comment: Do you use a build tool? If so, can you share the build configuration (e.g. pom.xml or build.gradle)?

Comment: @dan1st I don't have anything special there, just the dependencies and nothing else.

Comment: Note that annotation processors do not process dependencies. If you want to process your dependencies, those artifacts need to declare/use the annotation processor by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do it is to generate some sort of a dictionary in the first 2 modules, this could be a class that holds references to all generated types, for example each module might generate a class like this

```
@ModuleClasses({TypeA.class, TypeB.class, TypeC.class})    
public class ModuleATypeRegistery {
       
}
```

now in the third module you can define an annotation that can list those classes, maybe it goes into a package-info

```
@MyGeneratedClassesRegistry({ModuleATypeRegistery.class,ModuleBTypeRegistery.class})
package com.mycompany.sample;
```

Then you implement your third module annotation processor to also consider those package-info when it is needed

Comment: This should work. Thanks